# How to handle form validation (special characters) for multiple languages : AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, special-characters, multiple-languages

consider I have below form which I want to validate for multiple languages.

```
<form ng-submit="vm.transferCommunity()" name="transferCommunityForm">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="transferCommunityLogin" ng-model="vm.transferCommunity.login" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_ ]+$/" >
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="(transferCommunityForm.transferCommunityLogin.$invalid && !transferCommunityForm.transferCommunityLogin.$pristine)">Button</button>

<div ng-messages="transferCommunityForm.transferCommunityLogin.$error" ng-if="transferCommunityForm.transferCommunityLogin.$invalid">
  <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-message="pattern">Special Characters are not allowed</div>
</div>
</form>
```

The current pattern [`ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_ ]+$/"`] by which I am validating my form.
Its working fine for English language  but for the languages like Japanese, Chinese, French, German , it displays error message.

for example word `Reference` in English when translated to french becomes `Référence` and it clearly contains special characters but its valid.

How to solve these problem??

Any help is appreciated !!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying all the correct values, you can specify all the wrong values.

Create a regular expression that will contain all the wrong characters.

For example: `/[@!#$%^&*()\-+={}\[\]|\\/'";:.,~№?<>]+/i`.

This regular expression will look for all the wrong characters.

Since `ng-pattern` expects us to give a positive regular expression, we need to override the execution `ng-pattern`.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/781fpk7k/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.myPt = {
      regExp: /[@!#$%^&*()\-+={}\[\]|\\/'";:`.,~№?<>]+/i,
      test: function(val) {
        console.log(val);
        return !this.regExp.test(val);
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <form name="myForm">
      <input ng-model="firstName" name="firstName" ng-pattern="myPt" required>
      <br>firstName = <pre>{{myForm.firstName.$error|json}}</pre>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**P.S.** Maybe I forgot some wrong symbols. If need be, you can simply expand the regular expression.